# Modify existing bootstrap sidebar to collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've built my project in bootstrap which has a top navigation bar and a sidebar.

Now I need to make sidebar, collapsible like this:

http://www.makerstudios.com/

But sidebar in my project is on left side of the page. How can I make this sidebar collapsible with minimum possible changes?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are [many different approaches](http://blog.codeply.com/2016/05/18/bootstrap-sidebar-responsive-examples/) and most use a wrapper with `position:absolute`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple jquery.

First you need to set up the sidebar to be off-screen though. This can be done by adding a

```
.sidebar {
    left: -300px // For example
}
```

Then you need to make a jquery code, that listens on clicks on the button you want to be bring out the menu.

When the button is pressed, the jquery code should make the sidebar displayed again, and bring it to a visble range (left:0;)

```
<script>


$(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function open(){
        $('.sidebar').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
        });//opening it
    $("#close").click(function close(){
        $('.sidebar').animate({ left: '-200px'}, 500);
    });// 'Closing it'. Takin it back off -screen within the timewindow of 500ms
    });


</script>
```

So what you would have to do now, is setup the bar off-screen, and then create a buttons for your opening/closing.

This solution will make the sidebar go on top of the existing body, but if you would like it do be the same way as it is on the site you've linked, you just have to add a command to the jquery to move the content-partion(visible part) the same amount as the sidebar moves.

Comment: it's only hiding the sidebar , and leaving the blank space at the place of sidebar i don't want that blank space although when the menu is hidden other content on the page should increase it's width in order to fit the page

Comment: Then you could just make a     .content -div, which is contains everything BUT the sidebar, and just set the width of that div to 100% or 100vw, whichever you like.

It would really help if I could see the code myself.

Comment: I made you a codepen of a working example. But you should keep in mind that stackoverflow isn't a place for free code. You should learn these things yourself. http://codepen.io/Matsutus/pen/KzjVKm


It's not perfect, but for a quick doodle it should help. You can figure out the rest of your things yourself

Comment: I've used bootstrap quite a bit. It's just that you didn't provide much information. 

I gave you a working patch of code, which you could implement onto your site, and if that isn't working for you, then this isn't the right place for you.

If this solution didn't work, I suggest you go read some tutorials on jquery toggling and bootstrap elements at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp